# Move a 2D sprite in a curved upward arc in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Alright, so here's my problem.

I've been trying to create a sort of a visual day/night cycle in XNA, where I have an underlying class that updates and holds time and a Sky class which outputs a background based on the time that the class updates.

What I can't figure out though is how to make the moon/sun move in a curved upward arc that spans the screen based on what time of the day it is. The most problematic part is getting the Y axis to curve while the X axis moves as the time progresses.

Anyone that could help me here?

EDIT:
Alright, looks like Andrew Russels example helped me to do what I needed to do.
Although I had to expermient for a bit, I finally reached a suitable solution:
    float Time = (float)Main.inGameTime.Seconds / (InGameTime.MaxGameHours * 60 * 60 / 2);

```
this.Position.X = Time * (Main.Viewport.X + Texture.Width * 2) - Texture.Width;
this.Position.Y = Main.Viewport.Y - (Main.Viewport.Y * (float)Math.Sin(Time * MathHelper.Pi) / 2) - (Main.Viewport.Y / 2) + 50;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at the `Math.Sin` or `Math.Cos` functions. These are the [trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) you're looking for.

[image]

Something like this (giving a position for `SpriteBatch`):

```
float width = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
float height = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
float time = 0.5f; // assuming 0 to 1 is one day
Vector2 sunPosition = new Vector2(time * width,
        height - height * (float)Math.Sin(time * width / MathHelper.TwoPi));
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code.)

Comment: Thank you very much, had to modify it for my Viewport and all that, but now it works like a charm. See my solution on question post.

Comment: And if you wanted to include a night cycle you could use Math.Sin with Math.Cos to create a full circular motion

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [Curve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.curve.aspx) class.